# Where can I find a Metz P -76 power pack schematic?

Tags: flash, lighting, repair, metz

I love my Metz P-76 and want to repair it. I have contacted Metz Germany and no reply. Metz Canada tried to find something but were unsuccessful. There does not seem to currently exist any American representative.

Comment: Whilst I think this is completely off-topic, I'm not against giving it a day or so just in case anyone has access to the document, just to help someone out as a one-off. [Though I can see the meta-future downside in letting this go more frequently]

Comment: @Tetsujin Please edit the question to be less non-conformant. I don’t disagree with your empathy. But the big problems are not being off topic. There is actually an on topic question in there.

Comment: What is wrong with the unit?

Comment: Do you mean the wall wart or the battery pack?  The wall wart is probably just a bog-standard DC power supply that can be replaced by any other supply of the same voltage, amperage, and polarity.  Check it with a voltmeter and see if it is producing the right voltage.  If the problem is the battery pack itself, then the question becomes "How is it misbehaving?"  The answer to that can tell us a lot about how you'd go about fixing it.  So try editing the question to provide a lot more info about the incorrect behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I need to find what the adjustments are inside the pack.   I changed the batteries (old) and now it does not function quite correctly.  There are two multi turn potentiometers inside.  I have tried contacting Metz, no reply. Many dealers to no avail.  So I am trying this forum.   Thank you for the assistance with this.  